# Конвертер PHP в другой язык для реализации многопоточности

Tags: php, c++, c#, многопоточность, конвертер

В какой язык можно переконвертировать скрипты PHP?

Нужно для адекватной многопоточности, потому что корявая у меня уже есть.
Ну и для десктопного приложения.

Нравится C#, потихоньку его учу, но, кроме *Phalanger* ничего не нашел. Если ничего не найду путного - буду его копать.

Нужно мне это затем, что есть несколько приложений на PHP, которые очень сложно\энергозатратно\вообщеникакнизя\лень переписывать с нуля.

Comment: Очень размытый вопрос (языков, умеющих работать с многопоточностью - великое множество), автоматических конверторов скорее всего не существует. На PHP обычно поднимают какой-нибудь AMQP-сервер и поднимают некоторое количество рабочих процесссов, которые присасываются к этому серверу.

Comment: В любой можно. Только к уже существующей корявости добавится новая, но уже *нечеловеческая*, разобраться с которой   будет еще тяжелее.

Comment: Ну я постарался приблизить к цели, упомянув c#. Что-то подобной структуры. Или Java.

Я просто, так сказать, новичек, поэтому не знаю, есть такие сервисы или нет.

Спрашиваю, потому что уже ни один и не два раза писал свои велосипеды и буквально через день, после написания находил такие же. Вот, думаю, может есть такое, а я и не знаю. :)

Comment: Эмм...а зачем было писать код, требующий асинхронного выполнения, на PHP? PHP, как говорится, "рожден чтобы умереть". Пришел запрос - вы его обрабатываете, и шлете ответ. Ни о каких ожиданиях других потоков в данном случае не может быть и речи.

Comment: @Ganster41, сказать по правде - потому что это единственный язык(исключая JS), который я знаю на таком уровне, чтобы писать то, что мне нужно. :))
Причина банальна.

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко: Если у вас возникает потребность в многопоточности — это наверняка означает, что вы «выросли» из PHP, и вам нужен более продвинутый язык. PHP всё же очень простой язык by design.

Comment: Хм. Тогда я из него "вырос", только занявшись. Потому что ООП C# по-наалу было сложно осилить, а писать хотелось. Поэтому первое "приложение" мое было адской помесью PHP+JS(JQuery), с асинхронным Ajax'ом, которое реализовывало многопоточность посредством параллельного вызова скриптов. :)

Comment: @Ganster41 это было верно лет пять-десять назад, но сейчас PHP уже активно окреп и, например, в области консольных утилит (пусть только и для разработчиков на PHP). Немного другая сиуация, в общем, хотя исходно было действительно так.

Comment: @Etki То есть PHP вырос из языка для веб-страничек, и теперь на нём даже (?) можно писать консольные утилиты? Ну прогресс, ага.

Comment: @Discord, на нем, кстати, можно писать и десктопные приложения. ;)
Но вообще, тема про конвертер. Я так понял, или о нем никто не знает, или его не существует.

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко Если даже конвертер существует, вам не понравится код, который он сгенерирует. Забудьте про похапэ как страшный сон и приступайте к переписыванию вручную. Заодно приведёте архитектуру в порядок. Если код писался в духе "не знаю ООП, надо написать хоть как-нибудь, пусть и будет лапшой" — этот код точно должен быть переписан.

Comment: Согласен, поэтому не так давно большинство кода обвернул в классы. :)
Хотя, я согласен с Вами. Жаль, что нет таких ресурсов. Зато есть идея стартапа :))

Comment: @Discord, на нем оконные приложения писать можно (php-gtk, целая ide phpdevel или как-то так и прочий вырвиглазный ад). А основная область применения - не только веб-страницы, но и консоль.

Comment: "Зато есть идея стартапа" - мыслей про конвертеры из X в Y было уже столько, что на очень нехилое кладбище идей наберётся. Подобные конвертеры могут представлять скорее академический интерес, на практике же они либо невозможны в принципе, либо будут хоть немного приемлемый код выдавать для языков не сложней "Лого" :)

Comment: Ну, конвертер-то наверное возможен (и может даже неплохой). Только вот код он будет делать не для человека, а ТС судя по духу вопроса хочет получить код, который можно реально сопровождать (удобно отлаживать, расширять и т.д.). Вот в возможность написания *такого конвертера* я и сильно сомневаюсь.

Comment: Да до сопровождения дело всё равно не дойдёт. Хотя бы потому, например, что "выигрышные" подходы и конструкции одного языка при тупом переносе могут оказаться мягко говоря не самыми удачными в другом. Работать такой код может и будет, но как? И т.д., и т.п. BTW, на тему конвертеров - встречался как-то конвертер mysql в постгрес или наоборот, уже не помню точно. Не баз, а SQL-выражений в исходниках. Казалось бы - скл и скл, задача простая, проще, чем из языка в язык. Ан фиг, всё равно без ручного разбора наконверчённого никак...

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите в сторону Gearman, в php нет многопоточности, зато есть многозадачность. Можно написать воркер и запускать его через cli либо рулить с помощью supervisor.

Comment: Между прочим, автор вопроса в одном из своих ответов привел [ссылку](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads) на проект, который добавляет pthreads (многопоточность) в PHP.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Да где угодно можно прочесть что php изначально планировался как однопоточный язык программирования и вся многопоточность это какие либо костыли. Другое дело многозадачность которую можно получить за счет [PCNTL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) либо [Gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php), Я предпочитаю работать с Gearman очень удобно добавлять задачи для воркеров (которые управляются за счет supervisor т.е. 1 скрипт запускается множество раз с разными именами и пидами), либо можно вообще передать задачу в другой язык программирования т.к. у gearman довольно обширное api

Comment: @avp, и кстати в том же ответе я посоветовал посмотреть в сторону языков, которые действительно ее поддерживают. потому что я перепробовал много классов, библиотек и т.д., но все равно везде как-то не так, то ли из-за того, что у меня руки не из того места, а может из-за того, что нужно уже переходить на что-то другое.

Comment: @АндрейЦапенко, видимо это из-за того, что в реальности многопоточность по причине своей внутренней сложности (похоже, независимо от языка) это последнее средство, которое надо пробовать при проблемах с производительностью. Просто это направление сейчас стало модным (IMHO его специально пропагандируют производители железа).

Comment: Ну я не приверженец всего модного и т.д., мне главное, чтобы выполняло свою функцию. А для моих нужд многопоточность это не роскошь, а необходимость. А на php может быть такое, что выполнение функции по какой-то мистической причине пропустилось, то есть идет запуск потоков в цикле, 100 запустилось и отработало, а одна-две не захотели. :) Чуть позже задам тут вопрос по языкам, такое разнообразие и не знаю куда податься. :)

Comment: В gearman к сравнению никаких мистических пропусков нет, так же в транковых версиях есть возможность хранить очереди в БД. Да возможно многозадачность чуть медленнее многопоточности, но все равно это очень мощный инструмент который может спасти в высоконагруженных проектах. И да многопоточность/многозадачность это не мода, а необходимость выжимать все соки из железа, иначе какой толк от 8, 12 и тд ядер процессора на сервере?